# Fill MYSQL table with records based on date interval

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop, sql-insert

In MYSQL v5, I want to create a linear forecast per customer (CUSTID) based on the latest order date, the average date interval (days) between orders and the average order value, all of which I have already queried per CUSTID.

So I want a record created with columns CUSTID, average order value, orderdate for each date between the latest order date for that customer and a max date, let's say '2019-12-31' .

Based on somewhat similar questions here on stack I attemped a while loop in a stored procedure (below) but I struggle to get any meaningful output although I have the idea I'm not that far off the right path. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
Input Data sample
+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
| CUSTID | LatestDate | AvgInterval | OrderValue |
+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|   1001 | 01/11/2019 |          15 | 400.00     |
|   1002 | 17/10/2019 |           8 | 250.00     |
|   1003 | 04/11/2019 |           7 | 500.00     |
+--------+------------+-------------+------------+

Expected output table
+--------+------------+------------+
| CUSTID |    Date    | OrderValue |
+--------+------------+------------+
|   1001 | 16/11/2019 | 400.00     |
|   1001 | 01/12/2019 | 400.00     |
|   1001 | 16/12/2019 | 400.00     |
|   1001 | 31/12/2019 | 400.00     |
|   2002 | 29/10/2019 | 250.00     |
|   2002 | 10/11/2019 | 250.00     |
|   2002 | 22/11/2019 | 250.00     |
|   2002 | 04/12/2019 | 250.00     |
|   2002 | 16/12/2019 | 250.00     |
|   2002 | 28/12/2019 | 250.00     |
|   3003 | 13/11/2019 | 500.00     |
|   3003 | 22/11/2019 | 500.00     |
|   3003 | 01/12/2019 | 500.00     |
|   3003 | 10/12/2019 | 500.00     |
|   3003 | 19/12/2019 | 500.00     |
|   3003 | 28/12/2019 | 500.00     |
+--------+------------+------------+

The while loop I attempted to use for this:
while 
    (select max('Date') from OutputTable) <= '2019-12-31'
do
    insert into OutputTable
        (select 
            ip.CUSTID, 
            date_add(
                max(
                    ip.LatestDate, 
                    max(op.'Date')
                    ),
                interval ip.AvgInterval DAY    
                ) as 'Date',
            ip.OrderValue
        from
            InputTable ip,
            OutputTable ou
        )
end while
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you could use a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select USTID, latestDate Date, AvgInterval, OrderValue from mytable 
    union all
    select USTID, Date + interval AvgInterval day, AvgInterval, OrderValue 
    from cte 
    where Date <=  '2019-12-31' - interval AvgInterval day
)
select USTID, Date, OrderValue from cte order by USTID, Date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d2bacaca8bbc30f96eb651f3c8b523e)**:

```
USTID | Date       | OrderValue
----: | :--------- | ---------:
 1001 | 2019-11-01 |     400.00
 1001 | 2019-11-16 |     400.00
 1001 | 2019-12-01 |     400.00
 1001 | 2019-12-16 |     400.00
 1001 | 2019-12-31 |     400.00
 1002 | 2019-10-17 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-10-25 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-11-02 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-11-10 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-11-18 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-11-26 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-12-04 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-12-12 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-12-20 |     250.00
 1002 | 2019-12-28 |     250.00
 1003 | 2019-11-04 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-11-11 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-11-18 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-11-25 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-12-02 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-12-09 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-12-16 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-12-23 |     500.00
 1003 | 2019-12-30 |     500.00
```

---

In earlier versions, typical solutions would include a table of numbers.

```
select USTID, t.latestDate + interval d.n * t.AvgInterval day Date, OrderValue
from mytable t
inner join (
    select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
    union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
    union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
) d
    on t.latestDate + interval d.n * t.AvgInterval day <  '2019-12-31'
```

This would handle up to 10 future intervals. You can expand the subquery with more `union`s to manage more than that, or better yet you can materialize a number table and `join` it in the query.

Comment: Thanks GMB, I;m going to attempt your proposal right away. One check: I expect that d.latestDate should be t.latestDate in your example, right?

Comment: @ArjanPelle: yes you are correct, I just fixed that typo.

Comment: Welcome @ArjanPelle!